# How do you designate more than one "system drive" on Win10Pro64?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

To my previous understanding, when running a clean install the "system drive" is partitioned out and reserved for the OS.  I was under the impression that one "system" partition equates directly to one Windows OS installation instance; under that assumption, I had believed you can have more than one partition, but they would be separate installations of Windows OS and cannot be running concurrently.

I have a PCIE M.2 drive with lower capacity that I installed my Windows OS onto.  Unfortunately, for Windows store apps, the user isn't given any choice (none that's obvious anyway) to install apps onto alternate drives.  Once you run out of space, a dialogue prompt appears on-screen asking you to free up space, or "pick a system drive with at least ...".  I found that to be very odd, as there is a drop-down menu for you to select another drive, which currently for me only shows the one drive.  I have an additional SSD and two HDD's installed, but I was wondering if there's any method to "extend" the system partition onto the other SSD without basically installing another copy of Windows?

**EDIT:**
@Mokubai So I had quite the laugh with this one (but no, I wasn't amused).  First, I confirmed that -- just as you said -- there *is* a setting for it, as shown here:

[image: Screenshot 1]

As you may have noticed, it was already set to my other SSD.

Going to the other screen as you indicated, I double checked and noticed that *any* official Microsoft application that comes OEM has both options grayed out (which begs the question of why they even bothered to list them), and for the store apps that I installed myself, all of them appear to have been installed on my C:/ regardless (which begs the question of why they bothered to include the previous screen's setting).  And here's the kicker: when you try to move the application from the latter group, this message pops up:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Stellar performance, Microsoft, as usual.

I'm open to any other feedback regarding this, maybe there's some fix or workaround?

Comment: You can create separate partitions and install an OS to each partition, then modify the BCD file to create a boot option for it.  As to software and apps, it is not recommended to install software to a separate drive, as it will eventually create issues with Windows.  In WinPE, you could create a junction like [`cmd /c mklink /J "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps" "Z:\WindowsApps"`], howevever if you modify any permissions for the folder or it's contents, permissions should be reset to default, denying users access to that directory.

Comment: Microsoft has made a decision, that modifying the permission of the `WindowsApps` folder, will have weird effects on UWP applications.  The solution to the 0x80073d0b error is extremely easy to resolve, uninstall the application, and then reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

The "system" drive is the current drive that the Windows system is running from.  It is not an indication that the "system can use it", nor is it "a place to install things". It is, simply, the boot drive where your operating system is.

You do not need to, nor can you, set other drives as "system". It is a logical rather than physical designation and doesn't involve setting any drive attributes.

Depending on how your other drives are formatted you should be able to install or [move your applications to another drive](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-apps-separate-drive-windows-10) but you may have to make sure that the other drives are formatted as NTFS for this to work.

You can find the locations, and set the default Windows Store install location under `Settings` -> `System` -> `Storage` and then `Save locations`.

You cannot simply merge other partitions onto another to make it work, you just need to set things up properly.

Comment: I thought that settings page was pertaining to libraries?  I don't recall seeing anything regarding where applications get installed to, but I haven't looked at it in a while.  I *do* recall going through and selecting other drives for each available choice, and for sure that didn't stop store apps from saving to C:/ (unless it was added in a recent update?), but I'll double check as soon as I get home!  Thanks

Comment: @Arctiic while there are a number of settings in there for, documents, music, video and so on, there is a setting for Windows Store Apps ("New Apps") at the top. From the Storage panel you can also click Apps & Features and any app that can be moved to another storage device will have a `Move` button as well an an `Uninstall` button.

Comment: Edited to include my experience with the settings you pointed out, unfortunately it doesn't work as intended.  I forgot to mention in the edit, but yes I confirmed all the relevant drives are formatted as NTFS.

Comment: Okay, that is all very odd. Is there a `Windowsapps` folder on that drive? It sounds like a permissions issue, are you able to simply reformat the drive using Windows so that everything gets set up cleanly and retry?